# Выпадающие списки и отображение div с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

проблема с выпадающими списками и отображением блока div по результату выбора значений их этих выпадающих списков.

у меня есть два выпадающих списка

Выпадающий список "А"

```
<select onchange="showDiv_t(this)">
 <option value = 1>Local product</option>
 <option value = 2>Import product</option>
</select>
```

Выпадающий список "Б"

```
<select onchange="showDiv_p(this)">
 <option value = 1>Product not for sell</option>
 <option value = 2>Product for sell</option>
</select>
```

И у меня проблема с отображением div (допустим их 4). Как сделать так , что бы когда я выбирал из выпадающего списка "А" 1 значение, а в списке "Б" выбирал значение 1. то мне отображалось только div с классом inputs_1 и dropzone_2. а когда значение 1 списка = 1, а значение второго списка = 2 , то в случае пред. выбора скрывались дивы и отображался div с классом inp_loc_f_sell и dropzone_1

```
<div class="inputs_1" id="inp_loc_n">
    <input type = "text"></input>
</div>

<div class="dropzone_2" id="doc_loc_n">
    <input type = "file"></input>
</div>


<div class="inp_loc_f_sell" id="inp_loc_s">
    <input type = "text"></input>
</div>

<div class="dropzone_1" id="doc_loc_s">
    <input type = "file"></input>
</div>
```

Дальше ситуация похожае. Если в списке "А" выбран второй пункт , а во в списке "Б" выбран = 1 то должны отобразиться div c классом inputs_1_imp и dropzone_2_imp, а если в списке "Б" тогда должен быть div с классом inp_imp_f_sell и dropzone_1_imp

```
<div class="inputs_1_imp" id="inp_imp_n">
    <input type = "text"></input>
</div>

<div class="dropzone_2_imp" id="doc_imp_n">
    <input type = "file"></input>
</div>

<div class="dropzone_1_imp" id="doc_imp_s">
    <input type = "file"></input>
</div>

<div class="inp_imp_f_sell" id="inp_imp_s">
    <input type = "text"></input>
</div>
```

я пытался сделать с помощью js.

```
    function showDiv_t(elem){
    if(elem.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_n').setAttribute("id" , "dis");
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_n').setAttribute("id" , "dis");
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_s').setAttribute("id" , "dis");
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_s').setAttribute("id" , "dis");
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_n').setAttribute("id" , "act");
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_n').setAttribute("id" , "act");
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_s').setAttribute("id" , "act"); 
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_s').setAttribute("id" , "act");
    } else if(elem.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_n').setAttribute("id" , "dic");
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_n').setAttribute("id" , "dic");
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_s').setAttribute("id" , "dic"); 
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_s').setAttribute("id" , "dic");
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_n').setAttribute("id" , "act");
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_n').setAttribute("id" , "act");
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_s').setAttribute("id" , "act");
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_s').setAttribute("id" , "act");
    }
}
function showDiv_p(elems){
   if (elems.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_s dic').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_s dic').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_s dic').style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_s dic').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_n act').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_n act').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_n act').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_n act').style.display = "block";
} else if (elems.value ==2){
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_s dic').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_s dic').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_s dic').style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_s dic').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('inp_imp_n act').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('doc_imp_n act').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('inp_loc_n act').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('doc_loc_n act').style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers